# Can't PUT customer in Rest Api Magento2 - fails to complete

Tags: magento2, customer, rest-api, bug, save

How do you PUT (update) a customer using the rest api?

I have a ticket open on github, but I was wondering if I'm just doing this wrong..

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5115

I've created a customer in admin.  I've noted the entity id. It is 22.

I'm attempting to PUT using the rest api to myhost.com/rest/V1/customers/{{myEntityId}}

The actual URL is http://192.168.5.65/rest/V1/customers/22 just to avoid confusion.

I'm sending the following json:

```
{
    "customer": {
        "firstname": "NewMitchell",
        "lastname": "NewThompson"
    }
}
```

Magento documentation states you only need to send the properties you want to update.

I'm expecting the customer object to be updated, but its actually trying to create a new customer.  I'm seeing this message come back:

```
{
  "message": "Please enter a customer email.",
  "trace": "#0 /var/www/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/VersionControl/AbstractEntity.php(90): Magento\\Customer\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Customer->_beforeSave(Object(Magento\\Customer\\Model\\Customer))\n#1 /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\VersionControl\\AbstractEntity->save(Object(Magento\\Customer\\Model\\Customer))...blahblahblah
```

I'm afraid I may be doing it wrong, but at the same time, I think I may have identified a bug.

Can anyone test this and see if it works or not?  I'm using Magento CE RC3, but i've tested it on Magento CE 2.0.6 and it doesn't work there either.

Comment: Have you get any solution for update customer for work PUT method ?
I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you look at the documentation you'll find that actually the email is not optional so is needed in order to update the customer

```
customer-data-customer-interface {
id (integer, optional): Customer id ,
groupId (integer, optional): Group id ,
defaultBilling (string, optional): Default billing address id ,
defaultShipping (string, optional): Default shipping address id ,
confirmation (string, optional): Confirmation ,
createdAt (string, optional): Created at time ,
updatedAt (string, optional): Updated at time ,
createdIn (string, optional): Created in area ,
dob (string, optional): Date of birth ,
email (string): Email address ,
firstname (string): First name ,
lastname (string): Last name ,
middlename (string, optional): Middle name ,
prefix (string, optional): Prefix ,
suffix (string, optional): Suffix ,
gender (integer, optional): Gender ,
storeId (integer, optional): Store id ,
taxvat (string, optional): Tax Vat ,
websiteId (integer, optional): Website id ,
addresses (Array[customer-data-address-interface], optional): Customer addresses. ,
disableAutoGroupChange (integer, optional): Disable auto group change flag. ,
extensionAttributes (customer-data-customer-extension-interface, optional),
customAttributes (Array[framework-attribute-interface], optional): Custom attributes values.
}
```

but if you try with the email at the current release you'll see there also  another param that is not optional (problably the documentation has to be updated). here is the very least needed to do the update:

```
{
  "customer": {
  "email": "email@here.me",
  "firstname": "firstname new",
  "lastname": "lastname new",
  "website_id": 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Apparently i'm an idiot. While i was waiting around for some answers, I reinstalled magento and now it works fine using POSTman. I'm sending the email and website ID as you suggest, and instead of reporting that the customer already exists, its updating it.  IDK.

Comment: i think it worked also before, you were just missing those param. welcome to the api jungle